# Having issue with View State on ASP.net Website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have just moved my dev website to a new computer and have got most of the web pages working. The only web pages that won't work are pages that have a postback. I know the code works fine which is why I think it is being caused by the view state. I keep getting this error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inputString
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inputString
```

This is the function where the error is being thrown:

```
Protected Overrides Function LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() As Object

    'Dim vState As String = Me.Request.Form("__VSTATE")
    PageStatePersister.Load()
    Dim vState As String = PageStatePersister.ViewState.ToString
    If Not vState Is Nothing Then
        Dim bytes As Byte() = System.Convert.FromBase64String(vState)
        bytes = vioZip.Decompress(bytes)
        Dim format As New LosFormatter
        Return format.Deserialize(System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes))
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Does anyone know why it is giving me this error? I can't find what is being passed to it that might be null, but I know the code itself does not pass any null values. Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the page has `EnableViewState="true"`

And verify the site-wide setting in web.config -

```
<pages enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" ... />
```